# How do I zoom in during image playback on a Nikon D3300?

Tags: camera-controls, image-review, nikon-d3300

I am new to the camera world. I have recently purchased a Nikon D3300. After I have taken a photo and try to view it on the screen, the plus (+magnification) button appears to do nothing when I try to zoom in on any of my pictures. I can zoom out but not in. Is this a setting I have set on the camera by accident or do I have a faulty button on the camera?

Comment: I would say that you have a faulty button. I am a Nikon shooter and the plus zoom in. I don't know any setting that can change this. How old is the camera?

Comment: That is odd.... how can you zoom out in review? Is the image already zoomed in? I have a D5500 with me and at the review one can initially zoom in but not out.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same model, try pressing and holding the zoom in (magnification with a + symbol inside it) for a few seconds. The camera should zoom into your photo, otherwise I'd return the camera to Nikon considering its not an old model, yours is probably still covered under warranty.

To all those people asking how he can zoom out without zooming in, I think what he means is when the camera zooms out to display several photos in order to be able to scroll through them faster.

Answer (score 0):

On some cameras (not sure about yours specifically) there's a subtle difference between the post capture review which occurs automatically after taking an image and the manual review initiated by pressing the arrow (>) looking button. Try zooming in while doing the other one.

(Also, how can you zoom out if you don't zoom in first?)

Comment: When I press the zoom out button I am able to see more than one picture  on the screen up until there are about 25 very small pictures on the screen

Comment: @philiptowning Given that, I'd say that there's a good chance the button is broken.

Comment: Can you zoom in again from the 25 small pictures screen with the + button?